# Modifying default Laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-artisan

I imported Laravels authentication using

> Php artisan make: auth

I'm trying to add an additional field to the registration page. The new field is a drop-down with two options of user type. Landlord/Tenant. When I click register, I'm redirected to the login script, with all my details still there, and the registration hasn't gone through. Anywhere else there might be an issue,

I have updated my model and remigrated it. I have also added it to the fillable array in the user class.

Register Blade Template

```
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="user-type" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">User Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select class ="form-control" id="user-type">
                        <option>Landlord</option>
                        <option>Tenant</option>
                      </select>
                      @if ($errors->has('user-type'))
                          <span class="invalid-feedback">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                          </span>
                      @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Register Controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'user-type' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'user-type' => $data['user-type']
    ]);
}
```

User Class

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user-type'
    ];
```

User Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('user-type');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

As you can see I have added user-type to all the places I think it needs to be added, am I missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating `HTML` elements, the thing that is being sent along in the request are values, those values are being `keyed` by the attribute called `name` on each field, and as you can see your select is missing that attribute, try:

```
<select class="form-control" name="user-type">
```

To test this out, you can put `dd($data);` inside `create` method, just before you create a new user

Comment: Lifesaver @Nikola. Such an obvious mistake